# set animation of opacity in vb.net in winrt

Tags: vb.net, xaml, animation, windows-runtime, opacity

i have in winrt and xaml following code:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
<DoubleAnimation
Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3"
AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
```

I want to convert this code to vb.net, so that I can set dynamically an animation to any image. My Problem is that in vb.net it seems that the line Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(xBewegung, "Opacity")
, where xBewegung is the doubleanimation, create an failure: WinRT-Informationen: Animation target not specified.

In some example I see something like new PropertyPath("Opacity"), but this seems not to work under winrt.

So what is the correct syntax.

Next Question: Is there anywhere a good source to see which strings I need, for example for a rotatetransform in need "Image.Angle", etc.

Thanks in advance, Basilius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the animation target with a reference to the object:

```
Dim sb As New Storyboard()
Dim da As New DoubleAnimation()
da.From = 1
da.To = 0
da.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
da.AutoReverse = True
da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
sb.Children.Add(da)

Storyboard.SetTarget(da, myImage) //myImage is the reference to the Image control
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "Opacity")
```

You probably have a reference. This way you do not have to handle the element names. The problem with `.SetTargetName` is WinRT's lack of `NameScopes`. Unforunately, I was not able to get it working. But `SetTarget` should be the better solution in many cases, anyway.

Comment: If I understand correct, then this code is not working? Is that right?

Comment: Okay, I copied your code and it works. Heureka, I have the same code. I cant believe it. I cant finde the difference, so I read your post again. NO it is not the same code and yes setTargetProperty and not setTargetName. I made today a view animations with transforms and all are working with setTargetProperty. I was so fixed to the second parameter, that I didnt see that I used setTargetName., Shame on me and I should contact an eye doctor. On the other animation are also a view questions opend, but I will ask better tomorrow, when my eyes got better. Thanks, Basilius